# Lost My sultan on gta online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I found a sultan some time ago and had it in my garage for ages. After modding up loads of my other cars, I finally decided to mod my sultan. I don't think I insured it but, I'm sure I destroyed an uninsured car before. I either insured it and got it back, or got it back and insured it. Somehow it shows in my garage space as destroyed when I phone my mechanic, but it's not in my garage and Mors Mutual are always engaged when I phone them. How do I get it back, and then insure it?

Comment: No insurance, no new car. There's no way yo get it back without having insurance prior to the destruction. Feel free to get a new car, mod it up, and spend the pocket change for insurance this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have any insurance on a car, you will be unable to retrieve it. That is the reason they added insurance in GTA Online. Make sure the next time you find a car off the street, you insure it as soon as you take it to the mod shop, so that you don't lose it again.